# Can't get custom annotation in Spring to work in Spock integration test

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, groovy, spock

I'm trying to use a custom annotation in order to set up my testing environment for a Spring MVC app that I'm implementing some Spring AOP Aspects into.  The setup involves a few Spring Annotations, so I'm trying to condense them down into one.  I'm able to get the annotation to show that it's not throwing an error on compile, but when I try to use it in my test cases, it doesn't have any effect.

Here's the annotation itself.

```
package com.oreillyauto.pricingweb.testingUtilities;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@ActiveProfiles("integration")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/application-context.xml",
    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/AOP-context-config.xml"
})
public @interface AcitvateTestProfile {

}
```

Basically just trying to combine the `@ActivateProfiles` with `@ContextConfiguration`.  It throws no errors, at least in Eclipse.

Here's my test case, which was written to test the start of an Spring AOP implementation I'm working on.  The test is written in Spock, which is a version of Groovy written particularly for testing (for those who don't know).  It uses JUNIT, and is really pretty similar...

```
package com.abc.efg.aspects

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

import spock.lang.Specification

import com.abc.efg.controller.UserController
import com.abc.efg.testingUtilities.AcitvateTestProfile

@AcitvateTestProfile
@Transactional("datawhseTransactionManager")
class ControllerAspectsSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    UserController userController

    def"placeHolder"(){

        given:
        def returner = userController.getListOfStoresThisUserCanUse(9999)

        expect:
        println("Did it show up?" + returner.toString() )

    }

}
```

I should note, if I put the `@ActivateProfiles` and `@ContextConfiguration` at the top of the test case, the test case will work just fine.

As it sits now, when I run the test case I'm given this:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getListOfStoresThisUserCanUse() on null object`.  Which makes me think that the test isn't using the application-context.xml, thus it can't find the beans it needs to inject them into my test case.

I've done a google search and found a few pieces I was missing there (`@Retention` and `@Target`), but even though everything seems to be written correctly, I can't get it to work.

And yes, this is all that I've done.  I was told that I wouldn't need to do any modifications to the web.xml or application-context.xml files we have in our app, so...  Hoping that's correct.  I'd rather stay away from writing XML beans because it's inconsistent with our general design pattern.  Buuuuut, if I have to I have to.  So if anyone can speak to that question, that would also be nice.

Comment: First step to take is to check whether this works in a plain JUnit 4 test (but not in Spock). If that's the case, the feature likely needs to be explicitly supported in spock-spring, and the best action to take is to file an issue at http://issues.spockframework.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that what you are trying to do (creating a meta-annotation) works well in Spring versions prior to Spring 4.
In any case, you could do the following (that works in older Spring versions too):

```
@ActiveProfiles("integration")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/application-context.xml",
    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/AOP-context-config.xml"
})
public abstract class AbstractSpringTest extends Specification {

}



@Transactional("datawhseTransactionManager")
public class ControllerAspectsSpec extends AbstractSpringTest {

}
```

Comment: The documentation for 3.2.4 makes it sound like this is possible...but perhaps "possible" and "works well" are different things, eh?  Not a bad idea to just create a parent class for all of our tests though...might have to take a look into that approach instead.

Comment: You are correct that it's suppose to work in older versions, but I don't know to what extent :). From what I gather from the documentation of Spring 3.2 and Spring 4, it seems that some of the annotations in Spring 3.2 work for meta-annotations, while this feature was greatly extended in Spring 4

Comment: It's not directly an answer I guess, but I did effectively the same thing.  So I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: @JayCarr Ok! If you find another solution, please post it back here :)